# Set full-page width inside a smaller div

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements: one with 15% width and the second 85%. In the second, I want to add a pop-up form on click with a background, but when I set 100% width on the pop-up it shows only on that 85% of the page.
Is there any way it can show on the full page? The element with the `pop-bg` class is a child of `#main`.

```css
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#main {
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
  background: black;
}

/* pop-up background */
.pop-bg {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.pop-bg').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.pop-bg').style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your HTML and JS too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the pop-up was the child component of some element with the width of 85% of the page. To make it really a popup, try making it really unrespect the normal DOM flow by some properties:

```css
.pop-bg {
  z-index: 1000; // to make it appear on top of others
  position: fixed; // to make it unrespect normal DOM flow
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; // make it full width as you wished
  .. another styles
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `100%` set the width to `100vw`. That means that  it is 100% of the viewport width.

Comment: Did you try increasing the `z-index`?

Comment: first block is my sidebar when i change width to 100vw in #main the sidebar covers that 15% of #main page i want side bar to be still next to main

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that you had 15% there, thought it was 100; make it `100vw` only in the `.pop-bg` and idk what else you could do other than changing some stuff

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add is `left: 0`.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.pop-bg').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.pop-bg').style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

#main {
  width: 85%;
  float: right;
  background: black;
}


/* pop-up background */

.pop-bg {
  /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); */
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  Sidebar
</div>

<div id="main">
  Main
  <div class="pop-bg">
    Pop-Up
    <br />
    <button class="close">
      Close
    </button>
  </div>
  <button id="button">Open</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shou this works but as using `position: absolute` (instead of `fixed`), when the page getting too long than normal view height, the popup will get weird because it's placed on the top of the page instead of on top of the current viewport.

Comment: Yes. That's why your answer is accepted and mine is not.